# MySQL undo logs not truncating

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, percona

I have MySQL Percona version 5.7, with 3 undo logs, but I don't know why truncating logs is not working.

I enabled `innodb_undo_log_truncate`, decreased `innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency` to 32

```
show global variables like '%_undo_%'

innodb_max_undo_log_size    1073741824
innodb_undo_directory   /data/mysql/
innodb_undo_log_truncate    ON
innodb_undo_logs    128
innodb_undo_tablespaces 3
```

```
show global variables like '%truncate%'

innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency    32
innodb_undo_log_truncate    ON
```

Executing `show engine innodb status` doesn't show any long running rollback transaction.

But my undo logs keep growing.

```
root@server:/data/mysql# du -h -c undo00*
598G    undo001
747G    undo002
346G    undo003
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The `innodb_max_undo_log_size` is measured in MB, so you've given each log file 1TB of storage space. You might want to scale this back a bit with something like: `SET GLOBAL innodb_max_undo_logs_size = 64G;`. Note that undo truncation takes place when the server finds itself less active, so you may not see the truncation take place immediately. I see you've set `innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency` to 32, which will have some performance impacts, but the truncation will take place sooner. Be sure to push this up to 96 or 128 after the logs are under control.

Comment: @Matigo: [The default value is 1073741824 bytes (1024 MiB).](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_max_undo_log_size) It is set to the default, which is 1Gb

Comment: i tried to set to the minimum allowed value: 10485760, but seems to not have any effect. 

The documentation says the value is expressed in bytes.

Comment: Suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: I think i found the culprit. I have History list length 269706860, so it take a lot of time before truncating logs. Now i have to find the optimal settings to speeding up this process

Comment: Note that the variable name is `innodb_max_undo_log_size` (singular log)